# Seeking an STM32 with wifi, BT, display and on-board debugger

Tags: sbc

I am seeking an STM32 with wifi, BT, display and on-board debugger (I think that they all have that, but am not 100% sure; I don't want to use a JTAG probe). Does anyone know of one?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a series called STM32WB with integrated WiFi and Bluetooth, there is a [STM32WB Nucleo](https://www.st.com/en/evaluation-tools/p-nucleo-wb55.html) available.

There is also an [F413 discovery board](https://www.st.com/content/st_com/en/products/evaluation-tools/product-evaluation-tools/mcu-mpu-eval-tools/stm32-mcu-mpu-eval-tools/stm32-discovery-kits/32f413hdiscovery.html) but it doesn't have Bluetooth, WiFi only.

Comment: I am aware of that one, but I don't see a display. Did I miss something? I'm not much good with hardware - soldering and such - but would be happy to accept a display which I can just snap on to the GPIO pins

Comment: Yeah, I saw your other question, I just failed to notice the word "display". Still - all ST's Nucleo boards have Arduino-compatible headers.

Comment: Indeed, I upvoted it, seems very similar and your answer probably answers it well.

Comment: STM32WB are great boards, and I will probably get one - without display - and keep my eye open for a display. I am looking for something with the functionality of an ESP3 (BLE & WiFi), which I can code in Ada and debug. I really would like a display,t hough; and the ability to use [Grove sensors](https://www.seeedstudio.com/category/Sensor-for-Grove-c-24.html) and controllers.

Comment: There are some STM Nucleo boards with on-board display [available](https://www.st.com/en/evaluation-tools/stm32-nucleo-boards.html#products). Thanx a 1,000,000 for your help. I will buy a few of these while waiting for my ultimate goal : [BLE5.1 with on-board eInk (or other display)](https://hardwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/12435/ble5-1-with-on-board-eink-or-other-display)