# BLE5.1(+) with on-board or snap-on display *with AoA and AoD*

Tags: displays, bluetooth-5, development-board

So, I just found [Papyr](https://www.cnx-software.com/2019/02/06/papyr-nordic-nrf52840-epaper-display/).

[image]

> Hardware Specifications
>
> ```
> Raytac MDBT50 module with Nordic nRF52840 BLE/802.15.4 SoC
> 1.54 inch 200x200 pixel red/black/white epaper display - GDEW0154Z04
> CR2477 coin cell holder
> Micro USB (device)
> RGB LED
> NFC (PCB) antenna
> Push button
> USB/Battery power switch
> Extra GPIOs
> SWD Programming header
> Mounting holes
> ```

I am looking for a similar device, but with BLE5.1, for it's [AoA/Aod](https://www.bluetooth.com/blog/new-aoa-aod-bluetooth-capabilities/) Location features, so that I can use it as a tracker.

Any small (dev) board with at least BLE ***5.1*** will do (I am processor agnostic), but it ***must***  support a display - either eInk or OLED (even TFT), but preferably something battery friendly - and it ***must*** be either on-board or easily connected with something like a Grove connector; absolutely no soldering or hardware knowledge required (would Arduino compatibility be an idea? Probably plenty of snap-on displays).

Also, just BLE 5.1+ is not enough, it must support AoA and AoD, or it is of no use to me.

A major bonus is an on-board debugger; failing that ability to us a J-TAG probe would be welcome.

Comment: STM Nucleo is Arduino compatible, so display should be no problem. But, alas, no 5.1 as yet - only Nordic have that

Comment: regarding ST, they have their own debuggers using SWD which can go as low as 10$: : https://www.st.com/en/development-tools/stlink-v3mini.html and in general for Cortex-M it's usually SWD due to the lower pin count.

Comment: There is also the FOSS [Black Magic Probe](https://github.com/blacksphere/blackmagic/wiki) but I had issues configuring my IDE to use a gdb server over VCOM.