# How to do directional finding with Bluetooth and UWB

Tags: bluetooth

Just jumped into the ocean of IoT and found myself drowning....

I am trying to make my small toy car(with remote) being able to follow me.

Have discussed with my hardware friend and was told to get

1. [UWB](https://www.aliexpress.com/item/1005002284315770.html?spm=a2g0o.cart.0.0.26fc3c00YJXtrI&mp=1) to detecting the distance
2. [Bluetooth 5.1](https://www.aliexpress.com/item/1005003035990314.html?spm=a2g0o.cart.0.0.26fc3c00YJXtrI&mp=1) for directional positioning

However when I searched online, I found so many variations for the Bluetooth 5.1. (It has to be at least BLE 5.1 to be able to do the directional positioning)

The one BLE I provided link here with title BLE 5.1, but then also having picture saying it supports Bluetooth 5.0 which makes me confuse about which exactly version it supports. Talked to the store staff, no responses.....

Can someone suggest a few products for the Bluetooth?

Also , could someone share some code for how to use them in Python or MicroPython, if no code available in Python, C++ is okay...

Comment: I too, am interested in location/direction (+1 & follow). Related questions: [Bluetooth Direction Finding - do I understand it correctly?](https://iot.stackexchange.com/questions/4639/bluetooth-direction-finding-do-i-understand-it-correctly) and [BLE 5.1 wearable dev board *with AoA and AoD*](https://hardwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/13654/ble-5-1-wearable-dev-board-with-aoa-and-aod) and [BLE5.1(+) with on-board or snap-on display *with AoA and AoD*](https://hardwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/12435/ble5-1-with-on-board-or-snap-on-display-with-aoa-and-aod). Let us know if you find